# Adding ground to the minus of the source

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, ground, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: the circuit in question]

I'm currently learning Kirchhoff's law and a circuit shown in the picture came up.
I had tested it in a circuit simulator and no current was shown to leak to the groud.
Could anyone explain what adding ground near the "minus" of the source does to a DC circuit?

Comment: Why do you think that any current should leak to ground? Where does that current go one it gets there (considering that current flows in a loop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different reasons for grounding depending on what world you're operating in.

**In the mathematical theory of circuit analysis,** the ground symbol in your circuit makes no difference whatsoever to the analysis of this circuit. It connects to nothing else, and thus has no effect — just as if it were a wire with the other end not connected to anything.

**In a simulation**, the simulator often benefits from having some chosen point on the circuit to identify as “always zero volts”. This makes the numerical problem the simulator has to solve better-defined. It also affects how the simulator reports voltage values.

**In practical circuit design in reality**, circuits may be grounded — or specifically *not* grounded (“floating”) — to manage how they are affected by electrostatic and electromagnetic influences from the environment. These cannot be represented on a circuit diagram or solved using circuit analysis, since the diagram specifically is not a representation of the physical shape of the circuit.

(“Ground” connections are also of interest whenever you send an electrical signal or power from one device to another, but in that case, they can be thought of as one large circuit — here I'm describing only the presence or absence of a ground from an otherwise isolated circuit.)

Answer (score 0):

In most electronic circuits the Ground symbol does not indicate a connection to The Earth or to anything else - it just marks the point in the circuit that we choose to call "Zero Volts" and use as a reference when measuring voltage elsewhere in the circuit.

Circuit simulators generally require you to mark some point in the circuit with a Ground symbol to give them a reference to use when calculating voltages elsewhere in the circuit.

In most ciruits this "Zero Volt" point will be the most negative point in the circuit, but in many analog circuits it will be the mid-point of the power supplies - you will have both positive and negative voltages in the circuit.  It may even be the most positive point, if the designer feels that is appropriate.

In AC power wiring and some radio antenna systems the Ground symbol may indicate an actual connection to the earth.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes the point where measured voltages are referred to in your simulation. So if you place a voltage measurement probe it will give a voltage in reference to the selected ground point.

If you add the ground point to any other point in your circuit the points will be shorted.